# What does 고 mean in 많았고요?

Tags: grammar

In the following sentences:

> 나와 내친구들은 치맥을 사랑해요!
>
> 그래서 지난주에 대구 치맥 페스티벌에 다녀왔어요.
>
> 사람들이 정말 많았어요. 치킨도 정말 많았**고**요.

(Source: 연세한국어 듣기와 읽기 2 - p.40)

According to my dictionary, there is an entry in 고 that means the following:

> Used at the end of a sentence, to express a question

However, all the examples use the interrogative tense.

> 남은 일은 누가 하고?
>
> 저녁밥은 누가 짓고?

So I'm not sure if it is correct. It also does not make sense in the context.

So what does 고 mean in the sentence and why is it used after all?

Comment: [-고요](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=83912)

Comment: @Klmo So it’s the 4th usage, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. -고요 is used to add something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, -고 is a suffix (어미) meaning "and"; it's normally seen in between clauses like:

> 사람들이 많았고 치킨도 많았어요.

However, it can also be placed on the second clause if it's a separate sentence, so the emphasis is changed somewhat, and it means something like "also, too"; since it's now at the end of the sentence we can add 요 as well for more polite speech:

> 사람들이 정말 많았어요. 치킨도 정말 많았고요. "There were a lot of people.  Lots of chicken, too."

Using -고 here connects the sentences better; if all your sentences just end in ordinary declarative endings (-았어요. --었어요. over and over) your speech / writing will lack cohesion; this is one way to make the sentences flow better together.